# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with SUM or MINUS MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sql-update, sql-insert

I was searching real hard for an answer but couldn't find one

I have this table

[image: main_inventory]

and I am using this query to update it (this query is a must because I have dynamic inputs from my frontend so I can update multiple rows)

```
INSERT INTO main_inventory(name,sellingPrice,purchasePrice,averagePrice,totalQuantity) VALUES("test1",20,5,27.5,23),VALUES("test2",20,5,27.5,50)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name),sellingPrice = VALUES(sellingPrice),purchasePrice = VALUES(purchasePrice),averagePrice = VALUES(averagePrice),totalQuantity = VALUES(totalQuantity)
```

thing is, if I run this query above. The table should be updated but I want the totalQuantity column to be added so the value of test1 should be 46 and test2 will be 73. I have no idea what to do

name column is unique and a key

I am doing the query with nodejs

```
  let query4 = `INSERT INTO main_inventory(name,sellingPrice,purchasePrice,averagePrice,totalQuantity) VALUES`
  for(let x=0;x<main_items.length;x++){
            if(x+1 == main_items.length){                
                query4 = query4+`("${main_items[x].item}",${main_items[x].sellingPrice},${main_items[x].purchasePrice},${main_items[x].averagePrice},${main_items[x].quantity})
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name),sellingPrice = VALUES(sellingPrice),purchasePrice = VALUES(purchasePrice),averagePrice = VALUES(averagePrice),totalQuantity = VALUES(totalQuantity)`
            }else{                
                query4 = query4+`("${main_items[x].item}",${main_items[x].sellingPrice},${main_items[x].purchasePrice},${main_items[x].averagePrice},${main_items[x].quantity}),`

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to current value of column that you insert into in the `UPDATE` part of the query, like:

```
INSERT INTO main_inventory(name, sellingPrice, purchasePrice, averagePrice, totalQuantity) 
VALUES ('test1', 20, 5, 27.5, 23), ('test2', 20, 5, 27.5, 50)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    name = VALUES(name),
    sellingPrice  = VALUES(sellingPrice),
    purchasePrice = VALUES(purchasePrice),
    averagePrice  = VALUES(averagePrice),
    totalQuantity = totalQuantity + VALUES(totalQuantity)  -- add to the original value
```