# How can I insert or update records from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, phprunner

I have two tables: **parts** (with *codice, pezzi, durata*) and **magazzino** (with *codiceM, pezziM, durataM*)

I want to add or update some records from parts to magazzino. What I would Like to do is:

1. check if *codice* is already present in the table **magazzino**, if not INSERT a record with *codice*, *pezzi* and *durata*.
2. if *codice* is already present in **magazzino**, sum and UPDATE *pezzi* and *durata* associated with *codice*.

I use phprunner to create database and insert a button that executes the code after selecting a record in parts.

Here is my code that execute with no errors but it gaves me no results.

```
$record = $button->getNextSelectedRecord();    
$cod=$record["codice"];     //variable assignments
$qnty=$record["pezzi"];
$time=$record["durata"];
$control=0;   //control variable

$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","provaMagazzino") or die("sorry     not connected");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM magazzino";    
$resultq = $con->query($sql); 


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultq)){     // check and update records in magazzino table
 echo($row['codice']);
 if ($row['codice']==$cod) {
 $row['pezziM']+=$qnty;
 $row['durataM']+=$time;
echo('durataM');
 $control=1;
 break;
 }

}

if ($control=0) {  //add new records al Magazzino if control variable is zero
$resultq->codiceM = $record["codice"];
$resultq->durataM = $record["durata"];
$resultq->pezziM = $record["pezzi"];
$resultq->descrizioneM = $record["descrizione"];
$resultq->Add();
}
```

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: ok i will try. I have doubts how to use it....sorry but it is first code for me

Comment: Also, do not mix `mysql_` calls and `mysqli_` calls in your script.  In fact, you should not be calling any `mysql_` functions in any modern code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160742/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-sum-or-minus-mysql this should show you how to add in the UPDATE clause.  And https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235549/2943403

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/q/6107752/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13466647/2943403

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/64208178/2943403

Comment: I find your question Unclear.  How does the `parts` table fit in? You should probably set up a fiddle and express your desired outcome as part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your data with mysql only

```
SELECT p.codice, IFNULL(p.pezzi, 0) + IFNULL(m.pezziM,0) AS updatedPezzi,IFNULL(p.durata,0)  + IFNULL(m.durataM,0) AS updatedDurata FROM parts AS p
left join magazzino m on p.codice = m.codiceM
```

IFNULL is added just to be sure that your data will not be lost if the record does not exist in magazzino table.
The result will be data that need to be inserted into magazzino table and you can customize it with `WHERE` condition to calculate specific rows
After that you can insert this data from php to mysql again if `INSERT ON DUPLICATE` is not good for you.
There are a lot of cases. As I see the `codice` column should be unique so for me [insert on duplicate key update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is the best choice here

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i want to create new records independent from first table. I can do this operation by grouping and sum, but if i modify first table i will loose these "groups"

Comment: It will create new records if the records does not exist in magazzino table. And values in new records will be the same as in parts table. The same thing you write on php. Just try to run select I provided and you will get my idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this correct?

```
  $record = $button->getNextSelectedRecord();    
   $cod=$record["codice"];     //variable assignments
   $qnty=$record["pezzi"];
   $time=$record["durata"];    
   
   INSERT INTO magazzino(codiceM, pezziM, durataM)
   VALUES ('$cod', '$qnty', '$time')
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   codiceM= values($cod)
   pezziM= pezziM+ values($qnty)
   durataM= durataM+ values($time)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is it correct? Probably.  Is it insecure? Yes. Is it a duplicate? Probably.